# How to inject null for unregistered services

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have a decorator and an associated service that looks like this:

```
public interface IAdditionalDataService<TResult, TModel>
{
    TResult PopulateAdditionalData(TResult model, 
        params Expression<Func<TModel, object>>[] properties);
}

public class AdditionalDataDecorator<TQuery, TResult, TModel> 
    : IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>
    where TQuery : QueryBase<TResult, TModel>, IQuery<TResult>
    where TModel : ModelBase
{
    private readonly IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> _decorated;
    private readonly IAdditionalDataService<TResult, TModel> _additionalDataService;

    public AdditionalDataDecorator(IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> decorated,
        IAdditionalDataService<TResult, TModel>  additionalDataService)
    {
        _decorated = decorated;
        _additionalDataService = additionalDataService;
    }

    public TResult Handle(TQuery query)
    {
        var result = _decorated.Handle(query);

        if (query.RelatedDataProperties != null && query.RelatedDataProperties.Any())
            result = _additionalDataService.PopulateAdditionalData(result,
                query.RelatedDataProperties.ToArray());

        return result;
    }
}
```

The decorator wraps a query handler so that the results are manipulated by the `AdditionalDataService` and then returned.

The issue is not all of my query results will need an AdditionalDataService, so not every possible TResult has an associated AdditionalDataService implementation.  Simple Injector throws an exception if I try to use the decorator without a valid AdditionalDataService implementation for the corresponding Type.

What I need Simple Injector to do - only for AdditionalDataService - is if it doesn't find an implementation for the corresponding type inject "null". From there I can test for null before calling into the service.

**So my question is**

How can I tell Simple Injector to inject null when it encounters a request for a service that hasn't been registered, instead of throwing an exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should *never* inject `null` into your application components' constructors. This is bad practice, because it complicates your code with null checks. A component should simply always be able to assume that it gets a value. Because of this, Simple Injector is built to make it (almost) impossible to inject `null` values into constructors.

Instead you should use the well-known [Null Object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern), which is what @manji is referring to. But instead of using the `ResolveUnregisteredType` event, there is a much easier way to do this.

I assume that you register your `IAdditionalDataService<TResult, TModel>` implementations using `Register` much like this:

```
// Simple Injector v3.x
container.Register(typeof(IAdditionalDataService<,>),
    new[] { typeof(IAdditionalDataService<,>).Assembly });

// Simple Injector v2.x
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IAdditionalDataService<,>),
    typeof(IAdditionalDataService<,>).Assembly);
```

A fallback registration can now be registered as follows:

```
// Simple Injector v3.x
container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(IAdditionalDataService<,>),
    typeof(EmptyAdditionalDataService<,>),
    c => !c.Handled);

// Simple Injector v2.x
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(
    typeof(IAdditionalDataService<,>),
    typeof(EmptyAdditionalDataService<,>));
```

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an *`'EmptyAdditionalDataService'`* (that does nothing) and return it for unregistred services using [Container.ResolveUnregisteredType Event](https://simpleinjector.org/ReferenceLibrary/html/E_SimpleInjector_Container_ResolveUnregisteredType.htm).

You can then check if it's an instance of `EmptyAdditionalDataService` in the `Handled` method.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of solution I needed, but couldn't put my finger on it.  Thank you!

Comment: You are correct, but it's much simpler to use `RegisterOpenGeneric`, because it has built-in support for this.

Comment: Sorry but I ended up changing the accepted answer, as I think @steven has made very valid points.