# parameter passed from constructor NRE ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, simple-injector

I used WebForms (legacy) + ASP.NET MVC + SimpleInjector

```
public abstract class CustomBaseController : Controller
{
    protected User user;
    protected IAppDbContext repo;
    public CustomBaseController(User user, IAppDbContext repo)
    {
        this.user = user;
        this.repo = repo;
    }
}
// my controller
[MyCustomAuthorize]
public class MyCustomController : CustomBaseController
{
    public MyCustomController(User user, IAppDbContext repo) : base(user, repo)
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostMethod()
    {
        user.Name = "NewUserName"; // throw NullReferenceException that user is null
        // some logic
        // some logger
    }
}
// user entity
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Email { get; protected set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; protected set; }

    public string FirstName { get; protected set; }
    public string LastName { get; protected set; }

    // and other properties
}

// Register DI
private static void InitializeContainer()
{
    var container = new Container();
    container.Register<IUserSessionManagement, UserSessionManagement >(Lifestyle.Scoped);
    container.Register<User>(() => container.GetInstance<UserSessionManagement>().UserSession, Lifestyle.Scoped);
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
}

// Wrapper for User 
public class UserSessionManagement : IUserSessionManagement
{
    public User UserSession { get; }
    public UserSessionManagement(IAppDbContext repo)
    {
        UserSession = (HttpContext.Current.Session[SESSION_AUTHENTICATED_USER] as User) ?? new User(Guid.Empty, null, null);
    }
}
```

- Authorization based on cookies.
- SimpleInjector resolves all dependency and [cannot null parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31600492/how-to-inject-null-for-unregistered-services). if parameter is null then an exception would be thrown when on the constructor.

I catch NullReferenceException (`user` is null) on `/PostMethod` request.
I was looking for any place where the reference could wipe. Nothing. Reference cannot rewrite. it looks like [GC](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/) has cleaned all the links.

**NOTE: I cannot reproduce this in debugging. I know about this problem from the logs.**

**NOTE1: `MyCustomController` created successful (`user` is not null). 
Post request to  throw expection that user is null.**

Comment: What does `CustomBaseController` do with the parameter?

Comment: @SLaks, updated

Comment: What do you mean by "loses" parameters, I'm really not understanding this question? If you debug the constructor, is `user` null? What exception message are you getting (if any)?

Comment: i get System.NullReferenceException for `user`

Comment: where did you register `user` as a dependency in simple injector.?

Comment: That other question you've linked to was asking about a *specific* DI library. Are you *using* [tag:simple-injector]?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in debug. I know about this  problem from logs.

Comment: @DavidG `MyCustomController` created successful. Post request to `/PostMethod` throw expection user is null.

Comment: Please show the code for the `User` class and the registration for `User`

Comment: It seems that `User` is runtime data, because you are changing the `Name` property inside the `PostMethod` method. Runtime data shoulde not be injected into components during their construction as explained [here](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/).

Comment: And please make sure your question is a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your current question is unclear and the problem is not reproducible.

Comment: @Steven unfortunately i can not reproduce this problem when debugging. This error occurs on prod server.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723493/base-controller-or-method-to-access-shared-resources/38723617)

We would have to see your CustomBaseController To see more.

```
public MyCustomController() : base()
{
}
```

You may just need a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Try and set your user object into the `TempData["NameYourObjectHere"] = user;` in your `abstract class CustomBaseController` and see if it still lives there or not.